# Proof showing perfect square and sum of digits is 2011

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there exists a perfect square so that the sum of its digits is
2011.

Comment: It is good practice to show some effort in the proposition of your problem. What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

$(10^{223} - 3)^2$ is a perfect square with digit sum 2011.

Comment: A little generalization: The digit sum of $(10^n-3)^2=10^n(10^n-6)+9$ will be $9(n-1)+9+4=9n+4$ for integer $n>0$